# FTP command to calculate storage taken by a given folder/path?

Tags: ftp

I'm a FTP/Linux newbie...

Is there a quick way to calculate the storage space taken by all files under a nominated FTP directory (including all sub directories)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current disk volume used by below command-

```
df -h
```

Below command will give size of all sub directories in current directory

```
du -sh * .
```

Comment: Do you happen to know whether its feasible to make this call via Java and the FTPClient?

Comment: @user2868835 If you have a Java question, ask a Java question and not a vague question as you did.